# Create an indicator column based on one column being within +/- 5% of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to populate the 'Indicator' column based on both charge columns. If 'Charge1' is within plus or minus 5% of the 'Charge2' value, set the 'Indicator' to RFP, otherwise leave it blank (see example below).

```
ID  Charge1  Charge2  Indicator
1   9.5      10       RFP
2   22       20 
3   41       40       RFP
4   65       80 
5   160      160      RFP
6   315      320      RFP
7   613      640      RFP
8   800      700    
9   759      800    
10  1480     1500     RFP
```

I tried using a .loc approach, but struggled to establish if 'Charge1' was within +/- 5% of 'Charge2'.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but just wanted to point out that if you have edge cases where `a/b = 1.05`, as in your data, you need to be extremely careful with rounding. In python (and in fact most implementations of float),  `9.5/10-1 < -0.05` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [190]: df.loc[df.eval("Charge2*0.95 <= Charge1 <= Charge2*1.05"), 'RFP'] = 'REP'

In [191]: df
Out[191]:
   ID  Charge1  Charge2  RFP
0   1      9.5       10  REP
1   2     22.0       20  NaN
2   3     41.0       40  REP
3   4     65.0       80  NaN
4   5    160.0      160  REP
5   6    315.0      320  REP
6   7    613.0      640  REP
7   8    800.0      700  NaN
8   9    759.0      800  NaN
9  10   1480.0     1500  REP
```

Comment: That's smart! + 1

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, create an 'indicator' series of booleans which depends on the percentage difference between Charge1 and Charge2.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
threshold = 0.05
indicator = ( (df['Charge1'] / df['Charge2']) - 1).abs() <= threshold
df.loc[indicator]
```

Set a threshold figure and compare the values against that.

Wherever the value is within the threshold, return true, and so you can directly use the indicator (boolean series) as an input into .loc.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `pct_change`

```
df[['Charge2','Charge1']].T.pct_change().dropna().T.abs().mul(100).astype(int)<=(5)
Out[245]: 
   Charge1
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8     True
9     True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cond = ((df['Charge2'] - df['Charge1'])/df['Charge2']*100).abs() <= 5
df['Indicator'] = np.where(cond, 'RFP', np.nan)


    ID  Charge1 Charge2 Indicator
0   1   9.5     10      RFP
1   2   22.0    20      nan
2   3   41.0    40      RFP
3   4   65.0    80      nan
4   5   160.0   160     RFP
5   6   315.0   320     RFP
6   7   613.0   640     RFP
7   8   800.0   700     nan
8   9   759.0   800     nan
9   10  1480.0  1500    RFP
```

Answer (score 1):

***Be very careful!***

In Python / float counting, `9.5/10 - 1 == -0.050000000000000044`

This is one way to explicitly account for this issue via `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.abs(df.Charge1.values / df.Charge2.values - 1)
cond1 = vals <= 0.05
cond2 = np.isclose(vals, 0.05, atol=1e-08)

df['Indicator'] = np.where(cond1 | cond2, 'RFP', '')
```